# Cloud scheduler HTTP function "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED". Google app engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-scheduler

We have a simple app in Google App Engine (python 3.6). We are trying to trigger a funciton (url) using Cloud scheduler. Using the console we have trigger that has the following frequency -

```
 1 0 * * * (America/New_York)
```

The target is
URL : https://project-name.appspot.com/url

When we click "Run Now" on the console we get the following error in the logs -

```
"status": "UNAUTHENTICATED", "url": "https://project-name.appspot.com/url", 
"@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.scheduler.logging.AttemptFinished", 
"jobName": "projects/project-name/locations/us-central1/jobs/url", "targetType": "HTTP"
```

Please help.

I ensured that the service account service-project-id-number@gcp-sa-cloudscheduler.iam.gserviceaccount.com is added to IAM.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/http-target-auth) here we need to post the entire URL.

But in reality just post the relative url. That is just do /url_extension